# How to Find Ram Market Bancor Connector Weight (CRR)

Tags: ram, bancor, ramcore

My question is how to discover the current CW for the bancor algorithm in the current RAM market.

Below you can see where in the system contract RAM and the RAMCORE token is created for the market upon the network's inception.

### [eosio.system.cpp code line 28:](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.cpp#L28)

```
if( itr == _rammarket.end() ) {

    //system_token_supply is set to current outstanding EOS supply                          

    auto system_token_supply   = eosio::token(N(eosio.token)).get_supply(eosio::symbol_type(system_token_symbol).name()).amount;                
    if( system_token_supply > 0 ) {
    itr = _rammarket.emplace( _self, [&]( auto& m ) {
    m.supply.amount = 100000000000000ll; 

    // 100 trillion smart token reserve created with "RAMCORE" token namespace

    m.supply.symbol = S(4,RAMCORE);

    // base.balance.amount set to outstanding free RAM, 64GB

    m.base.balance.amount = int64_t(_gstate.free_ram()); 
    m.base.balance.symbol = S(0,RAM);

    // EOS used for acting as counter party to trade (connector balance)    

    m.quote.balance.amount = system_token_supply / 1000; 

    // balance.symbol is given EOS token namespace

    m.quote.balance.symbol = CORE_SYMBOL;
}
```

---

Comment: If you have answered your own question please remove the Answer content from the Question and add it as an Answer to clarify this has been properly answered OK.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I cleaned it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Answer to this was provided:

[EOSIO RAM Market & Bancor Algorithm | *The* bytemaster July 4th](https://medium.com/@bytemaster/eosio-ram-market-bancor-algorithm-b8e8d4e20c73)

> Due to an unintentional configuration of the Bancor Relay weights on
>   the EOS blockchain, this parameter is set at **.05%** rather than **50%**.
>   This introduces some heavy slippage for buying and selling large
>   quantities and causes more volatility than desired.

Dan suggests hard coding a static **20% annual inflation** in RAM into the system contract along with the change in CW to **50%**.

---

You can find the weight by going:

```
cleos -u https://nodes.get-scatter.com:443 get table eosio eosio rammarket


{
  "rows": [{
      "supply": "10000000000.0000 RAMCORE",
      "base": {
        "balance": "11870290976 RAM",
        "weight": "0.50000000000000000"
      },
      "quote": {
        "balance": "5789275.3804 EOS",
        "weight": "0.50000000000000000"
      }
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

---

To provide some visual clarity on different CW's and how they affect price as supply is taken up, I've included a visual from the Bancor WP.

[image]

Comment: Why 10,000,000,000 RAMCORE?

Comment: The eosio token style/standard is to include a total supply.  This total supply will take a long time to get to.  It's interesting because there does not need to be a max supply.  Maybe a legal decision on b1's part.

Comment: but I can use bancor algorithm w/o having RAMCORE using this formula: RAM price (in EOS) = (n * quote.balance) / (n + base.balance / 1024) .......where, n = RAM needed (in KB)

Comment: Hm should be able to yes.

Comment: Thanks!...I just used in my dApp - Decentralized Ride Hailing Platform